# How do I label an axis in an RCharts nplot with a TeX expression?

Tags: r, tex, rcharts

In an RCharts nPlot, you can label an axis like this:

```
p1 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
p1$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Weight')
p1
```

In an R base plot, you can use TeX-like expressions like this:

```
plot(y = mtcars$mpg, x = mtcars$wt,  
     xlab = expression( "Weight "*bgroup("(",frac(lbs,1000),")") ))
```

But if I use the TeX-like expression in the nPlot:

```
p1 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
p1$xAxis(axisLabel = expression( 'Weight '*bgroup("(",frac(lbs,1000),")") ))
p1
```

then the nPlot will show the x-axis label with unformatted text like this:

```
*bgroup("(",frac(lbs,1000)
```

Using `as.expression()` instead of `expression()` results in an error:

```
Error in as.expression("Weight " * bgroup("(", frac(lbs, 1000), ")")) :  could not find function "bgroup"
```

Documentation for rCharts is still pretty limited.
Does anyone know if and how we can use TeX in rCharts?

Comment: The axisLabel is one especially hard thing to deal with in rCharts. Here an example on changing the font size goo.gl/h7SclH so making a subscript might be difficult. The problem is not from rCharts itself, it comes from the libraries it uses (in this case NVD3), which are really useful but lack documentation.and have some shortcomings. Probably you are in need of a javascript savvy to achieve a TeX type axis.